# Solving $AXB + X\odot C = D$

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

I need to solve the following equation for $X$ with $d$-by-$d$ matrices $A,B,C,D$ and Hadamard product $\odot$

$$AXB + X\odot C = D$$

Vectorizing all terms gives a solution with $O(d^6)$ complexity, which is intractable since $d\approx 1000$ in my application. Is there something I can do to get an estimate in $O(d^3)$ time?

To add more information about the structure, A,B,C are moment matrices. Specifically, for random variables $X,Y$ they are

$$A_{ij}=E[X_iX_j]$$
$$B_{ij}=E[Y_iY_j]$$
$$C_{ij}=E[X_iY_j]$$
$$E_t[D_{ij}]=C_{ij}$$

To give even more background, this comes up in problem of speeding up neural network training which for a single layer can be viewed as the following problem

$$\text{minimize}_{W} E[(x'Wy)^2]$$

Here $x$ and $y$ are random variables with shape $(d,1)$, the gradient is $E[x_iy_j]$ and the curvature is $E[x_i x_j y_k y_l]$. The goal is to use curvature information to obtain Newton-like correction to a noisy estimate of the gradient. Applying Isserlis theorem we can approximate curvature rank-4 tensor in terms of rank-2 covariance tensors which leads to matrices $A,B,C$ above. Substituting small sample estimate of gradient into $D$ and large sample  estimate of curvature into $A,B,C$, then solving for $X$, gives us a preconditioned gradient step.

Incidentally, using the same sample to estimate curvature and gradient, gives slightly simplified problem:

$$AXB + X\odot C = C$$

$A$ and $B$ are known to be ill-conditioned -- $n$-th eigenvalue is approximately $1/n$ and majority of eigenvalues are numerically 0, possibly 90% of all eigenvalues. Coincidentally, this ill-conditioning is what allows neural networks [to generalize](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/arora18b/arora18b.pdf). This implies that $C$ is also singular.

Comment: Can you clarify what $\odot$ means?

Comment: edited the question for clarity

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: I think what to do depends on the data $A, B, C$. 
If $A,B$ are invertible  and if $\|A^{-1}\| \|B^{-1}\|\|C\|<1$ (say for the Frobenius norms) then $X\mapsto X + A^{-1}(X\odot C)B^{-1}$ is invertible by a Neumann series, with the usual estimate for the remainder. On the other hand, if all coefficients of $C$ are non-zero, and $\|A \| \|B \|\|C^{-\odot}\|<1$ (here  $C^{-\odot} $ denotes the Hadamard inverse) one can invert instead $X\mapsto X + (AXB)\odot C^{-\odot} $. In both cases the above conditions on the norms are of course  stronger than needed for the convergence.

Comment: So I think a relevant point is: are your $A,B,C,D$ totally generic $d\times d$ matrices, or do they have any special feature that may address to a convenient  method?

Comment: I would try some iterative method like conjugated gradient possible with a preconditioner but the choice depends on $A,B,C$

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, there's indeed structure to the matrices, I've added everything that's known about them

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33499/solving-axb-x-odot-c-d-matrix-equation) on [scicomp.se].

Answer (score 3):

I am going to reduce your problem to another form. In a truncated version, this modified problem has been discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307402/is-there-any-efficient-solution-of-the-matrix-equation-axb-axb-cx-d?rq=1) and it seems there is no apparent efficient solution à la [Bartels–Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartels%E2%80%93Stewart_algorithm). However, it still might be valuable to have an alternative approach at hand, especially because such equations are being actively discussed (see T. Damm, *Direct methods and ADI-preconditioned Krylov subspace methods for generalized Lyapunov equations*, Numer. Linear Algebra Appl. 15, no. 9 (2008): 853-871) and because iterative approaches based on the standard Lyapunov solvers do exist.

Let us apply the `vec`-operation to the both sides of your equation using the commutativity of Hadamard product

$$
\mathrm{vec}(AXB)+\mathrm{vec}(C\odot X)=\mathrm{vec}(D).
$$

Now we use the following properties
$$
\text{vec}(ABC)=(C^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\text{vec}(B)
$$
and 
$$
\text{vec}(A\odot B)=\text{vec}(A)\odot\text{vec}(B).
$$
Thus
$$
(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\text{vec}(X)+\mathrm{diag}\!\left[\mathrm{vec} (C)\right]\mathrm{vec} (X)=\mathrm{vec}(D).
$$
Let us introduce a new matrix $U$:
$$
U=(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)+\mathrm{diag}\!\left[\mathrm{vec} (C)\right].
$$
Our goal is now to write it in the form of a Kronecker product.
$$
U=\sum_i \sigma_i V_i^\mathrm{T}\otimes W_i.
$$ 
This is known as the [nearest Kronecker product problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91651/nearest-kronecker-product). Using SVD decomposition on a permuted version of $U$ as Van Loan (J. Comp. Appl. Math, 123 (2000) 85) proposed, the factors $V_i$ and $W_i$ and the singular values $\sigma_i$ can be determined, and the original equation can be written as

$$
\sum_i \sigma_i\left(V_i^\mathrm{T}\otimes W_i\right)\mathrm{vec} (X)=\mathrm{vec}(D),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\sum_i \sigma_i W_i X V_i=D.
$$
Truncating the sum to just 2 terms, a standard Lyapunov equation is obtained.

Comment: This would just be a preconditioner though, right?

Comment: @NickAlger Why do you say so?

Comment: It seems to me that only $U \approx V^T\otimes W$, and they cannot be made equal in general (unless I am misunderstanding something). For example imagine $A=B=I$, and $C$ is a matrix filled with iid gaussian random entries. Then $U$ is diagonal, so $V$ and $W$ must be diagonal. But then equality is not possible, by a degree of freedom counting argument ($2d$ vs $d^2$).

Comment: @NickAlger Yes, you are right.